# I want to pass state value into compontDidmount

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass date from a input flild to a state and pass it into API. I am not able to do this in   `componentDidMount()`  but I am able to pass it in `componentDidUpdate()`

The problem is the that it becomes a endless loop.

```
export default class Med extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dateState: [],
    };

    this.dateHandler = this.dateHandler.bind(this);
  }
  dateHandler = (e) => {
    var dateselected = e.target.value;

    var date = moment(e.target.value).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log(date);
    this.setState({ dateState: date });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("====================================");
    console.log(this.state.dateState); //not able to console.log
    console.log("====================================");

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };

    axios.get("customer/medGET/?date=" + this.state.dateState, config).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ items: res.data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <input type="date" onChange={this.dateHandler} />
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it will get called in second attempt surely re rendering, not first

Answer (score 1):

This simplified version of your code shows that the state is available *just fine* in `componentDidMount`.

```js
class Med extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dateState: ["1"],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("====================================");
    console.log(this.state.dateState);
    console.log("====================================");

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <input type="date" />
        </tr>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Med />, document.getElementById("x"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="x"></div>
```

Comment: So your actual question is how to fetch data based on state changes?

Comment: this does not work . here the date from input fild is not being passed to state

Comment: I said this is a minimal example to answer your original question where you say you're not able to use state in `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: i am passing onchange input data to state

Comment: Yes, but `componentDidMount()` only gets called once per component instance lifecycle, on component mount. So it's not that you're "not able to console.log", it's just that the function doesn't get called more than once.

Comment: @AshishKamble Well, OP originally has an empty array, which they replace with a single Date, so it's weird in that sense too.

Comment: <input type="date" onChange={this.dateHandler} /> after the page is loaded iam trying to pass a input date to componetdidMount()

Comment: @viveknarayanankutty look careful the `react component life cycle` methods, then you will understand more